# Upgrade Java SE to Java EE as well as Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, upgrade

Currently I have Java SE on my linux machine and use Eclipse as my IDE. Is there a way that I can 'upgrade' my Java SE to EE? Since EE is just basically a few extra libraries...

Also I understand that Eclipse is by default only 'configured' to use Java SE, so if I upgrade to EE, should I install some extra plugins for Eclipse, get an entirely different version of Eclipse, so on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you want to achieve? Just download the Eclipse EE package if you wnat to do EE-development.

Comment: What I want to achieve, is do EE development. So what you're saying is that I should uninstall my current Eclipse. And download the Eclipse EE package? Does that include the Java EE libraries?

Comment: If you want Java EE platform in eclipse so, you have to install WTP in eclipse

Comment: It's a little bit more than 'just some extra libraries'. To do Java EE you will need a Server like Tomcat or something else. Also the eclipse-version has additional features. if i may ask: What 'additional libraries' do you think you get by using Java EE?

Comment: One of thoooose are we

Comment: Good advice to you.. don't try to install additional support manually.. its sometimes ends up as headache.. go for "Eclipse for Java EE developers".. and you can have any number (and types) of eclipse installations at the same time.. keep things simple and seperate..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a way that I can 'upgrade' my Java SE to EE? Since EE is just basically a few extra libraries...

Basically no.  Your characterisation of Java EE is incorrect.

Java EE is (typically) embodied as a "Web container" or "EJB application server", and large parts of it only make sense as part of a web container.  (And indeed, a large part of an Java EE *implementation* is actually specific to the web / application container.)

Having said that, some of the (abstract) APIs and some of the libraries are available as separate JARs and can be installed on a piece-meal basis.  And if what you want to do is *develop for EE*, then there are Eclipse plugins/features/whatever for that ...

---

> So basically it's recommended (or safer) to just remove my Java SE, install Java EE. Then remove Eclipse and install 'Eclipse for EE development' ?

There's no need to uninstall Java SE.  Indeed, some Java EE implementations *require* an installation of Java SE.  Read the instructions ...

For Eclipse, it might depend on your OS, but on Linux the "installation" process is simply expanding a ZIP file.  I've found that two Eclipse installations can coexist side by side in separate directories.

However ...

- Be careful that you don't accidentally install one version / edition *on top of* another one.  IIRC, the ZIP file's root directory is always "eclipse" ... which makes it a cinch to shoot yourself in the foot!  (Sigh).
- It is prudent to make a backup copy of everything including your old Eclipse install and your workspaces.
- In fact, some people recommend throwing away all of your workspaces and starting afresh by checking out / materializing projects from version control.

Comment: Great thanks stephen. So basically it's recommended (or safer) to just remove my Java SE, install Java EE. Then remove Eclipse and install 'Eclipse for EE development' ?

Answer (score 2):

You need Web Tools Platform (WTP) added to  Eclipse installation for Java EE development. First go to eclipse help menu->install new software->add the site
You can find the update sites here

http://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F

Comment: Great thanks for the reply. So that handles upgrading Eclipse. But how do I upgrade from a Java SE environment to a Java EE environment?